# Find a formula for $(f^i g^j)*(f^s g^t)$ of the form $f^a g^b$

Tags: abstract-algebra, functions

This is a problem from Herstein's *Abstract Algebra*

> Let $f(x,y)=(-x,y)$ and $g(x,y)=(-y,x)$
>
> Find a formula for $(f^i g^j)*(f^s g^t)$ of the form $f^a g^b$
> where $*$ is composition of the functions.

I have tried to use the fact that $g*f=f*g^{-1}$ but I couldn't simplify anything. I have also tried to write the functions as matrices since they are linear transformations but I couldn't get a simple formula with that either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We will prove that
$f^ig^jf^sg^t=f^{i+j}g^{t+(-1)^s j}$. To do that, we will use the following claim:

Claim: For $n=0,1,2,3$, we have $g^nf=fg^{-n}$

which can be proved by considering each of the cases $n=0,1,2,3$ separately. Note that since the order of $g$ is $4$, the above claim actually holds for all $n$.

Using this claim, we can calculate $f^i g^j f^s g^t$. Since $f$ has order 2, We have 4 cases: $i=s=0$; $i=s=1$; $i=0, s=1$; and $i=1, s=0$. We will call these cases 1, 2, 3 and 4 respectively.

Case 1: The expression becomes $g^j g^t= g^{j+t}$

Case 2: The expression is $fg^j f g^t=ffg^{-j}g^t=f^2g^{t-j}$

Case 3: We have $g^jfg^t=fg^{-j}g^t=fg^{t-j}$

Case 4: We have $fg^jg^t=fg^{t+j}$

In each of these cases, the formula holds. Therefore, $f^ig^jf^sg^t=f^{i+j}g^{t+(-1)^s j}$ for all $i$ and $j$.